# JPA / Hibernate How Add a business field to a the primary key of a many-to-many association with a join table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I have a many-to-many relationship using a join table with an extra column. That means that in my join table I have a composite primary key formed by two foreign keys. I also have a business column. 
I want to add the business column to the primary key so that I can be able to insert in the join table two records with the same foreign keys but a different value in the business column. Is it possible ? 
I am  using JPA and Hibernate to modelize my database
Here are more code details

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "ROUTE")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_ROUTE", sequenceName = "SEQ_ROUTE", allocationSize = 1)

    public class Route implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private Long id;
        private String name;
        private String origin;
        private String destination;
        private Date updateTimestamp;


        private Set<RouteSegmentAssociation> routeSegmentAssociations = new HashSet<RouteSegmentAssociation>(
                0);

        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pk.route", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        public Set<RouteSegmentAssociation> getRouteSegmentAssociations() {
            return routeSegmentAssociations;
        }

        public void setRouteSegmentAssociations(
                Set<RouteSegmentAssociation> routeSegmentAssociations) {
            this.routeSegmentAssociations = routeSegmentAssociations;
        }

        private List<Route> actualRoutes;

        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "referenceRoute", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        public List<ActualRoute> getActualRoutes() {
            return actualRoutes;
        }

        public void setActualRoutes(List<ActualRoute> actualRoutes) {
            this.actualRoutes = actualRoutes;
        }

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_ROUTE")
        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        ////
        }

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "SEGMENT")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_SEGMENT", sequenceName = "SEQ_SEGMENT", allocationSize = 1)
    public class Segment implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private Long id;

        private String name;
        private String entry;
        private String exit;
        private int distance;
        private Date updateTimestamp;

        private Set<RouteSegmentAssociation> routeSegmentAssociations = new HashSet<RouteSegmentAssociation>(
                0);

        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pk.segment", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        public Set<RouteSegmentAssociation> getRouteSegmentAssociations() {
            return routeSegmentAssociations;
        }

        public void setRouteSegmentAssociations(
                Set<RouteSegmentAssociation> routeSegmentAssociations) {
            this.routeSegmentAssociations = routeSegmentAssociations;
        }

        //getters and setters


    }

@Entity
@Table(name = "ROUTE_SEGMENT_CROSS")
@AssociationOverrides({
        @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.route", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ID_ROUTE")),
        @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.segment", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ID_SEGMENT")) })
public class RouteSegmentAssociation implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private RouteSegmentID pk = new RouteSegmentID();

    private int order;

    @EmbeddedId
    public RouteSegmentID getPk() {
        return pk;
    }

    public void setPk(RouteSegmentID pk) {
        this.pk = pk;
    }

    @Transient
    public Route getRoute() {
        return getPk().getRoute();
    }

    public void setRoute(Route route) {
        getPk().setRoute(route);
    }

    @Transient
    public Segment getSegment() {
        return getPk().getSegment();
    }

    public void setSegment(Segment segment) {
        getPk().setSegment(segment);
    }

    @Column(name="ORDER")
    public int getOrder() {
        return order;
    }

    public void setOrder(int order) {
        this.order = order;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return (getPk() != null ? getPk().hashCode() : 0);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (!(obj instanceof RouteSegmentAssociation))
            return false;
        RouteSegmentAssociation other = (RouteSegmentAssociation) obj;
        if (pk == null) {
            if (other.pk != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!pk.equals(other.pk))
            return false;
        if (order != other.order)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

I have a file contains actual routes and I want to build a referential of routes without duplicates. 
Two routes are "equivalent" if they have the same segments in the same order and the distance inside each segment is equal at 5% tolerance to the distance of the same segment in the other route. In this case I don't insert any new route. otherwise I insert a new route with new segments if necessary or using some already existing segments.

In some cases, I have the same segment in a route but with different order and this causes a problem with Hibernate when I try to retrieve segments from database before deciding to create new ones or not.

=====

> ```
> at xxx.xxx.xxx.save(RouteDS.java:328)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
> at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
> at $Proxy30.save(Unknown Source)
> at xxx.xxx.xxx.batch.RouteStats.inserteRoute(RouteStats.java:586)
> **Caused by: javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [xxx.xxx.xxx.RouteSegmentAssociation#RouteSegmentID [route=88457, segment=101943]]**
> at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1359)
> at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1315)
> at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:255)
> at xxx.xxx.xxxx.SegmentDAO.findByDescriminants(SegmentDAO.java:88)
> ```

It seems that Hibernates creates an association in side the session and when it tries to crew a new association between the same segment and route the second time, it fails because the association already exists.

I want to take the "order" field into account and allow many associations between a route and a segment if the order is not the same. How to deal with this

Thank you in advance.

Regards

Comment: If I understand you right, you need to  move 'order' to  RouteSegmentID.

Comment: Why not adding `order` as part of the composite PK?

Comment: Yes, I want to add order to the composite key but I don't know how to do it ?

Comment: I want to allow duplicate couples of (routeID, segmentID) unless the "order" is the same.